# Is Wolverine Like a Worm?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, regeneration

I have a few questions about Wolverine's regenerative properties.

So I heard that Magneto ripped out Wolverine's metal skeleton. This left Wolverine back to his bone form, so he had his bone claws.

My question is as follows... if Wolverine can survive his metal skeleton being ripped out of him and then he lives.

1. What would happen if you ripped his metal skeleton out then cut him vertically in two. Would he die, or regenerate? I believe if you do this to a worm, the worm will die.
2. If he'd die in Q1 then then what happens if you cut him horizontally at the waste?
3. If one half would regenerate the other in Q2, could he cut off his own arm and use it as a weapon, and have the arm he cut off regenerate?

Comment: I recall [one comic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Wolverine_vs._Hulk) where Wolverine got ripped in half by the Hulk and spent some considerable time crawling over to his legs to re-attach himself... but IIRC that was in the Ultimate Universe, and so it doesn't directly relate to the mainstream 616 continuity.

Comment: See also [Out of two organic lumps of Wolverine, what decides which one would regenerate to full Wolverine?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/out-of-two-organic-lumps-of-wolverine-what-decides-which-one-would-regenerate-t?rq=1)

Comment: If wolverine gets cut in two EQUAL halves, with each half able to regenerate him? Will we get two wolverines? ;)

Comment: Is Wolverine like a worm? Ask him! He won’t mind.