# If you cut Deadpool exactly in half, which half would regenerate?

Tags: marvel, deadpool, regeneration

If you cut Deadpool exactly in half, which half would regenerate and grow the rest of his body?

Or would both halves regenerate a complete Deadpool?

Has this happened in the comics? (I haven't had a chance to read them ALL).

Would this be a plausible way to 'clone' Deadpool?

**Edit**: I should also clarify that I'm talking about the possibility of him being split down the middle, not severed at the waist, which *has* happened in a comic and his legs simply grew back.

Comment: How do you cut someone *exactly* in half?

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14417/4918 "Out of two organic lumps of Wolverine, what decides which one would regenerate to full Wolverine?"

Comment: @Richard Very carefully.

Comment: @Richard A fair question. But lets hypothesize that someone has.. lets say.. used laser cutting equipment to split Deadpool exactly down the middle instantaneously.

Comment: Both parts would regenerate and we had 2 Deadpools. Double the awesome.

Comment: Do you think that the half with more mass, i.e the half that contained his heart and therefore more mass for example, would be the half that would regenerate? simply because it would be the side with greater mass? 

As in wolverine growing fingers back and not the fingers growing wolverine back.

I have also had someone mention that if both halves were exactly the same in mass, then would it depend on if he used his right or left side of the brain more, i.e logical/creative brain. Which was interesting

Comment: Both parts dont regenerate in the movie. only his hand grows. The hand doesn't grow the rest of the body!

Comment: @Cherubel, while you are correct in the context of a severed hand, I'm not referencing just the movie and i'm talking about him being split down the middle, not having a hand cut off. I'd expect him to regrow his hand as his body is of larger mass to the severed hand.

Comment: It's based on where the brain is IIRC. I do know there was a comic arc where he was killed, and there were 4 Deadpools for a brief period of time...

Comment: @Vogie the brain would be cut in half - one on each side.

Comment: You assume that Deadpool contains an even number of atoms...

Comment: @JaraDucroq Did you post this on Quora as well? I saw it there yesterday...

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria, no, that wasn't me. Someone must have beaten me to it.

Comment: I assume it'd be the sassier half.

Comment: About the exact split idea; in the appallingly bad movie Highlander 2, Sean Connery's character gets split down the middle to clone him. The casual way this is done and the way the healing is completely incompatible with the first movie's canon is a part of why it was the worst sequel ever made to an excellent first movie, IMHO.

Comment: You woudn't be able to cut him in half, he would kill you first

Answer (score 33):

[Deadpool - Volume 10: Evil Deadpool](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785160116), *Amazon*

This comic answers your question :)

> Would the real Wade Wilson please stand up? Deadpool returns to America, but he's not coming home alone! When a collection of Deadpool's discarded body parts meld to form an evil clone, the Merc With a Mouth faces off against himself for the crown of most hated former mercenary turned super hero turned pirate turned intergalactic bounty hunter. But their explosive confrontation brings the NYPD, Interpol and even Captain America bearing down on Deadpool, and he'll have to convince them all there's an even crazier, less principled version of himself on the loose!

Comment: So, TL;DR, both of them?

Comment: Since this answer deals with multiple chunks fused together, i can't consider it an answer, although it is really interesting!

Comment: Here we have parts who meld. But not regenerate. I don't think both halves will regenerate. I think the quantity to regenerate have to be less important than the existing parts...

Comment: @JaradDucroq Well... kinda... but if you cut him in half... twice... then the two "discarded" sides merge - assuming first one half regenerates and then the other leaving two opposite sides to then merge... (It'd be interesting to see two left sides merge together though)

Answer (score 23):

During the Dark Reign storyline Deadpool has a cross over with the Thunderbolts which ends with his head being cut off. Everyone is left to believe that this act would leave him dead as he would not be able to regenerate from this.

[image: Blond woman: You want to keep head for trophy? Guy in suit: Do I look like a sentimentalist? Burn it and get back to work.]

However, it is later found that he is alive and Deadpool credits it to Taskmaster having sewed his head back on his body sometime after the fact.

[image: Deadpool showing the stitches around his neck to the audience, but speaking to Taskmaster: It took real stones for you ta come back and sew my head back on, and I want you to know I won't forget it.]

Therefore, if split perfectly down the middle it's reasonable (for a comic?) to assume that Deadpool would not regenerate at all until his head and/or brain was brought back together to heal before any other body parts could regenerate.

Comment: So you're saying that he would be incapable of regenerating unless his brain was in one whole piece?

Wouldn't his head just have very slowly grown a new body if it was severed at the neck, seeing as his brain is in one piece?

Also, in the movie SPOILER ALERT!!    He is stabbed in the head, damaging his brain and he is able to regenerate this damage, so realistically, couldn't he just regen the missing half of his brain, if he was split in two?

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the case. I believe earlier in this storyline he has another brain related injury and is shown having issues recovering until his brain has regenerated.

Comment: I suppose there are inconsistencies in regards to the way Deadpool recovers from brain injuries, likely down to the artistic direction of different authors and the movie director

Comment: This is Deadpool we are talking about. Inconsistency is the name of the game.

Comment: Didnt he regenerate after being eaten by a LOT of Squirrels in a comic ? Or did I dream that he battled Squirrel Girl and Lost ?

Comment: @Des that sounds like a great story. I haven't heard of it though. I've only mainly read Daniel Way's run with Deadpool along with his recent time in X-Force so I might have missed it if it's out there.

Comment: Deadpool, Red Dwarf, and consistency don't mix.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Evil Deadpool, there was also the case where it was revealed that (due to an incident in 2008) Deadpool had been merged with Madcap, when Thor disintegrated them both into a pile of dust and then they regenerated together in one body:

[image: Deadpool and Madcap regenerating together]

(Madcap is the white speech bubble, which had been with Deadpool since Deadpool volume 2 in 2008, but was until this 2014 Deadpool Annual issue unexplained.)

This is relevant to the question because, at the end of the 2014 Deadpool Annual, he manages to get Luke Cage and Thor to split him in half (!):

[image]

This, of course, splits apart Madcap and Deadpool:

[image]

So, at least under specialized circumstances... that is what would happen.

Comment: Notice that it’s whatever half Deadpool imagines himself in... He implies that if he and Madcap both think “right” they’d still be in the same body.

Answer (score 3):

This is derived from practically all the answers above. Please credit them with 99% of any credit this gets.

From all the various answers and from current knowledge of brain anatomy, it seems that the two halves of the brain are not identical, and they fulfill different functions. Direct communication between the two halves of the brain seem necessary to the regeneration process, and that is not enough. The head must be connected to the body (sew it back together?). Can we call it regeneration then? It seems more like resurrection or reanimation.